# DOMContentLoaded is not getting triggered while visiting few sites. Any workaround?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox extension. My extension needs to get notified when a page completes loading. To implement this I am using DOMContentLoaded event. This works fine most of the times. But while visiting few sites (like nytimes.com), this event is not getting triggered at all. I am not sure whether these sites are using some special scripts.

Is there any workaround for this? Or is there a better way to implement what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMContentLoaded` may not be what you need...

According to MDN

> Fired at the page's Document object when parsing of the document is
>   finished. By the time this event fires, the page's DOM is ready, but
>   the referenced stylesheets, images, and subframes may not be done
>   loading; use the "load" event to detect a fully-loaded page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko-Specific_DOM_Events

So, it is possible that nytimes.com and others my be using frames or complex CSS and that is why you are not getting the correct trigger.

As mentioned above, the "fix" is to

> use the "load" event to detect a fully-loaded page